# java.lang.IllegalStateException crash only on Android TV devices

Tags: androidx, android-tv

I see quite a few crashes of the following only on Android TV devices:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod

java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod (AppCompatViewInflater.java:479)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:437)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6597)
  at android.view.View.performClickInternal (View.java:6574)
  at android.view.View.onKeyUp (View.java:13216)
  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch (KeyEvent.java:2734)
  at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent (View.java:12450)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1896)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1896)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1896)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1896)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1896)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1896)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1896)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1896)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1896)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1896)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent (DecorView.java:428)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent (PhoneWindow.java:1820)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent (Activity.java:3361)
  at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent (ComponentActivity.java:122)
  at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent (KeyEventDispatcher.java:84)
  at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent (ComponentActivity.java:140)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent (AppCompatActivity.java:599)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3090)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent (DecorView.java:342)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:5045)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:4913)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4434)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4487)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4593)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4461)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4650)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4434)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4487)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4461)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4434)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4487)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4626)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:4787)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run (InputMethodManager.java:2571)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback (InputMethodManager.java:2081)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent (InputMethodManager.java:2072)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished (InputMethodManager.java:2548)
  at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished (InputEventSender.java:141)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:326)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:160)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6718)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Since there are a lot of Android TV devices running the app, the crash is still rare. The stack trace does in indicate any app's source code, so I am clueless about the crash now.

I wonder if anyone could shed some light on this crash to point me in the right direction in searching for the culprit.

The following charts show the devices with this crash:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what logging system you're using to aggregate the crashes, but if you are able to look at a single instance of it, the IllegalStateException should tell you the method name, view type, and ID where this is happening.

If that's not available to you, you'll want to look for instances of `android:onClick` in your XML files. AppCompatViewInflater uses reflection to find the method to trigger, but this is done lazily since reflection is expensive. In other words, you'll have something like `android:onClick="handleMyClick"` in an XML layout. When the user triggers the click, AppCompatViewInflater attempts to find a `handleMyClick(view)` method with the given Context, working through any ContextWrappers until it finds a matching method. If it doesn't find one that matches, it throws the exception you're seeing.

The most likely culprit is that there is an Activity for mobile that implements the onClick method declared in the XML layout and an Activity for TV that does not. Another option is that the View with the onClick attribute is only easily/obviously accessible via a dpad.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. The stack trace is from the Google Play console. I pasted everything I copied from the Google Play console. There are numerous onClick events, so it is tough to narrow the scope. I am hoping one user will contact us after a crash to let us know which button he clicks to lead to this crash.